# Congruence proof involving $x$ and a summation of its digits.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Let $(x_n, x_{n-1},x_{n-2},...,x_0)_{10}$ be the representation of $x$ in base $10$. I was requested to prove that

$x \equiv x_0-x_1+x_2-x_3+...+(-1)^nx_n \mod{(11)}$.

I started by noticing that $11 \equiv 1 \mod 11 \implies 11^k \equiv 1 \mod 11 \implies z11^k \equiv z \mod 11$, for $k>0$. I supposed one of these three facts would turn to be useful, but I hardly found a use for them in my attempts.

I know what I essentially have to prove is that

$$x-(x_0-x_1+x_2-x_3+...+(-1)^nx_n) = x - \sum_{0}^n (-1)^nx_n =11m$$

(*i.e.*, it's divisible by $11$). I have not, though, found a way to prove this at all. How would one go about proving these?

Comment: You should start by noticing that $x=10^{n}x_n+10^{n-1}x_{n-1}+\cdots+10x_1+x_0$ then taking the $\pmod{11}$ of that. Also, $11\not\equiv1\pmod{11}$, which is probably why you are having trouble proving this.

Comment: 11 is congruent to 0 mod 11 .  Consider if digits do sum in this way, such as for 2695. Now consider the algorithm which cuts this number up into 2200 + 440 + 55. Use this algorithm on a number whose digits alternating sum is 0 to prove the problem.

Comment: It will also be useful to note that $10\equiv -1\mod{11}$, so that $10^k\equiv 1$ or $-1\mod{11}$ depending on whether $k$ is even or odd.

Answer (score 1):

Since $10\equiv -1\mod{11},\;\;$ we get that

$10^k\equiv (-1)^k\mod{11}\;\;$ for all $\;\;k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Moreover

$x=x_0+10x_1+10^2x_2+10^3x_3+\ldots+10^nx_n$,

therefore

$x\equiv x_0+(-1)x_1+(-1)^2x_2+(-1)^3x_3+\ldots+(-1)^nx_n \mod{11}$

that is

$x\equiv x_0-x_1+x_2-x_3+\ldots+(-1)^nx_n \mod{11}$.